# How to cast a reference with an object's original class?

Tags: java, casting, processing

I'm working on a GUI library for Processing, and I have got a class `Component`. I have a bunch of other classes that extend `Component`: `Label`, `Button`(Which extends `Label`), `Panel` and `Icon`. These classes continue just the "logic" part (position, text, function checking if they are clicked etc...).

The class `Panel` has inside of it an `ArrayList`of `Component`, and you can add to it buttons, labels etc...

To display the components I decided to use a class `Theme`, which has inside some overloadings of the function `display(Component component)` (one for `Label`, one for `Button`, one for `Panel` etc...).

Inside `display(Panel panel)`, at some point, I display all the children of the panel, but, instead of treating them (the children) as `Button` or `Label`, it treats all of them as `Component`. How can I solve this ISSUE?

1. I've already tried to use a method `display()`inside the classes `Component`, `Button` etc... it works partly, but it gives some "coding problems": to override the function display you have to create a new class (Example: GreenBackgroundButton extends Button{}). Also, by putting all the function in an external class, you can control all the grapihcs of you Program with a single class, so you can have the same background for all the components with a single function `displayBackground()` etc...
2. `instanceof` can't be used, because, if I have to use it to cast the children of the panel, the user can't create custom components, because they would be displayed as `Component` not as `TextField` (example).
3. I've tried casting directly `display((Button)panel.getChildren.get(0))`, but, as it Should, when I use a label, it gives an error (as expected).
4. I've tried casting like this too: `panel.getChildren().get(0).getClass().cast(panel.getChildren().get(0))`, and it doesn't work, I don't know why. (I tried all its variants, like creating an external object etc...)
5. If you need more code, you can ask...

```
public void display(Panel panel) {
    println("panel");
    if (panel.isVisible()) {
      pushMatrix();
      translate(panel.getX(), panel.getY());
      displayBackground(panel, #AAAAAA);

      for (int i = 0; i < panel.getChildren().size(); i++) {
        this.display(panel.getChildren().get(i).getClass().cast(panel.getChildren().get(i))); //THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ISSUE
        //println(panel.getChildren().get(i).getClass().cast(panel.getChildren().get(i)));
      }
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
```

```
Theme basicTheme;
Button close;
Panel panel;

void settings() {
  size(400, 600, P2D);
}

void setup() {
  basicTheme = new Theme();

  close = new Button();
  close.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 25);
  close.setText("close");

  panel = new Panel();
  panel.setBounds(50, 200, 200, 200);
  panel.add(close);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  basicTheme.display(panel);
}
```

I expect to see on the canvas a working button inside the panel, instead of seeing a component. I don't have any particular error I can think of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `instanceof` is almost always a hack, and is probably a symptom of a bad design.

What you've described sounds exactly like an existing Java library called the [Abstract Window Toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) (AWT), so you might consider "borrowing" some of their design patterns.

- `Component` is an abstract class that defines an abstract `paint()` function. The `paint()` function takes a `Graphics` argument. More on that in a second.
- `Button` and `Label` extend `Component` and overide the `paint()` function.
- `Graphics` is a class that contains functions like `drawRect()` and `setBackground()`. It encapsulates shared drawing code, similar to what I think your `Theme` class would do.

If I were you, I would consider taking a similar approach for your library.

I'll try to address some of your other comments:

> Example: GreenBackgroundButton extends Button{}

Favor [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) for cases like this. You should not need to extend `Button` to set a background. Instead, have a `setBackground()` function in the `Button()` class (or in the `Component` class).

> Also, by putting all the function in an external class, you can control all the rapihcs of you Program with a single class, so you can have the same background for all the components with a single function displayBackground() etc.

It sounds like this belongs in your `Component` class.

Also, taking a step back, I would encourage you to avoid the temptation to [over-engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) a solution. You might think you need a complicated design with several levels of inheritance and many different classes, but chances are a simpler design will probably get you almost everything you need. Specifically, I don't see a huge benefit to extracting any code into the `Theme` class. I would probably put everything directly in my component subclasses like `Button` and `Label`.

Comment: Actually, I've used Java Swing, (and Java AWT too), and the main problem I had with it, was the one that I had to extend the UI class for every component, to create a custom UI (and it resulted in tons of custom UI classes, and some of them were duplicates), that's why I wanted to "externalize" the graphic part. Thinking about it, your answer is right, but partially: the `Component` will extend the abstract class `Displayable`, and an `UI` instance too. I thank you for the answer, it helped me decide how to continue.